# How to use bash function with arguments in make file

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to use the bash function in the make file. Without argument, it's working, but how I can use it with arguments.

```
all : 
        foo () { echo $1} ; foo "hello"
```

Comment: You need a semicolon before the `}`. Without that, the shell will parse "}" as an argument to the `echo` command, and never find an end to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing bash code inside Makefile require special handling for all the characters that are special to Make. In particular, '$', which must be escaped (doubled). Also note that ';' is required before '}'.

In general, when writing bash/sh snipplet inside Makefile, `${XYZ}` (or `$(XYZ)`) will refer to MAKE variable, and `$$XYZ` (or `$${XYZ}}`) will refer to the sh variable.

```
all:
        foo() { echo $$1 ; } ; foo "hello"
```